# How to query with Range Query in elasticsearch (certain fields probably not exist )

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to query the following 3 records with Range Query.
The first record hasn't the `EndDate` field and the second hasn't the `StartDate` field.
If the field doesn't exit, it'll not be used as a condition.

```
StartDate   | EndDate
2015/01/01  | -
-           | 2016/01/01
2015/01/01  | 2016/01/01
```

Query:

```
"bool" : {
             "must" : [
             {"range" : {"StartDate" : { "lte" : "2015-06-01" }}},
             {"range" : {"EndDate" : { "gte" : "2015-06-01" }}}
             ]
       }
```

If I use the above query, I can only get the third record.
In fact, I'd like to get all 3 records.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write complex bool query manually handling each case. I think it'll work but it's not most convenient and efficient thing probably. I don't know a better way though

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
           {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": 
                 {"exists": { "field": "EndDate" }},
            }
           },
           {"range" : {"StartDate" : { "lte" : "2015-06-01" }}}
          ]
        }
      },
     {
        "bool": {
          "must":[
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": 
                   {"exists": { "field": "StartDate" }},
            }
           },{"range" : {"EndDate" : { "gte" : "2015-06-01" }}}
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {"range" : {"StartDate" : { "lte" : "2015-06-01" }}},
            {"range" : {"EndDate" : { "gte" : "2015-06-01" }}}
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

EDIT: I consulted the docs and turned out I used `exists` query incorrectly in my original answer. It's fixed now